# GStreamer playback on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: streaming-video

I have a TCP stream open on a Raspberry Pi and I would like to play back that stream on another Pi in full screen. Unfortunately I get a cryptic error message with the code that works on my Mac. How do I make it work on my Pi?

Host:

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=IP_ADRESS port=5000
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=IP_ADRESS port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Error message on Pi:

```
Caught SIGSEGV
#0  0xb6c03c80 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0xb6cee528 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0
Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch-1.0 1333' to continue debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.
```

Basically I would like to be able to exchange and display the camera input from two pi's over a local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the Raspberry Pi 1 as it is working with a Pi 2. 
But the stream is very slow on the Pi 2, which I suppose has something to do with decoding(?). On my Mac the stream is fluent with a delay of >200ms.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.